# silverlight preview read only(?) on VS 2008

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2008, silverlight-toolkit

i´m having som trouble with the silverlight XAML preview on my visual studio 2008. 
I cant drag and drop any control, but when I make changes to the XAML code, I can see the changes relflected as you can expect. It seems that the preview is read only or something like that.

Can Someone tell me if there is a known issue with this?.

These are the versions of what i got installed:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008   91605-270-1850275-60788
Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008
Version 9.0.30729.146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio 2008 [only allows preview mode](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2010/03/18/Silverlight_3_designer_preview_only_in_Visual_Studio_2008) with Silverlight. VS 2010 provides the full designer. You could use Expression Blend or get Visual Studio 2010 Express.